# Missing MainStoryboard Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I have a problem with my Xcode project, In my MainStoryboard.storyboard it's showing missing(red) In "Build Phases" -> "Copy Bundle Resources". Then I can edit the StoryBoard but their changes are not shown when I run the application. Everything works fine until I change to use Xcode 5.

I can put here an image because I don't have enough reputation, but its showed in red in "Copy Bundle Resources" section.

Can anybody help me? I don't know what happened to my MainStoryboard.

[image]

Comment: try to upload screenshot on dropbox or somewhere else and share its link.

Comment: Try dragging the storyboard into the "bundle resources" window that you have in your image

Comment: Let me try, I'll let you know

Comment: Did you move the storyboard's location? (the file within your projects directory)

Comment: No I haven't moved it